# Unable to unsubscribe from pubnub in android

Tags: android, pubnub

I have used unsubscribe(channelname) to unsubscribe from pubnub but my android application is unable to unsubscribe from this channel. I am getting messages from this channel.

I have used following code to subscribe from pubnub

```
 mPubnub = new Pubnub("", subsriberkey);
            mPubnub.setCacheBusting(false);
            mPubnub.setAuthKey(authToken)
```

;

```
mPubnub.subscribe(channelname, pubnubConnectionCallback);


private Callback pubnubConnectionCallback = new  Callback() {
        @Override
        public void connectCallback(String channel,
                                    Object message) {

            showToast("SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:"
                    + channel
                    + " : "
                    + message.getClass()
                    + " : "
                    + message.toString());
        }

         @Override
         public void disconnectCallback(String channel,
                                        Object message) {
             showToast("SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:"
                     + channel
                     + " : "
                     + message.getClass()
                     + " : "
                     + message.toString());
         }

         @Override
         public void reconnectCallback(String channel,
                                       Object message) {
             showToast("SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:"
                     + channel
                     + " : "
                     + message.getClass()
                     + " : "
                     + message.toString());
         }

         @Override
         public void successCallback(String channel,
                                     Object message) {
//           showToast("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
//                     + message.getClass() + " : "
//                     + message.toString());
             showToast(message.toString());
         }

         @Override
         public void errorCallback(String channel,
                                   PubnubError error) {
             showToast("SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel "
                     + channel + " : "
                     + error.toString());
         }
    };
```

Following code to unsubscribe from pubnub

```
mPubnub.unsubscribe(channelName);
```

Comment: Hi there!  Can you paste your code?  Also cc support@pubnub.com and we'll track.

Comment: as @PubNub wrote, please add more code.

Comment: I have problem in unsubscribe only not to send message, not to subscribe. I only used above code not more than that.

Comment: Thank you!  We are reviewing.

Comment: Just updating that we are investigating the issue and will have more details as we discover `android` development issues with our **websockets** and **tcp streaming management** layers in the Android SDK.

Comment: Just double checking. I saw that your variable names for your **PUBNUB** instances are not matching!  - `mPubnub` vs `mpubNub`.

Comment: i have used same instance. I got an issue Forbidden error as i check from log.

Comment: I'll ping the dev team on this issue again.

Comment: This is not reproducible in-house so far... please reach out to us at support@pubnub.com and we'll work with you from there. Thanks! geremy

Comment: Thanks. i will give you update after applying new jar

Comment: I am using pubnub.unsubscribe function and then pubunb.disconnect(). It is working well for me..

Comment: This is still an issue with pubnub. Any solution?